# gsub apply combination in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use gsub on every column of a dataframe to remove some characters, I have tried using apply to do this without success:

```
data<-apply(data,2, function(x) gsub("£","",data[x]))
```

returns error

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, x) : undefined columns selected
```

I know it works if I do

```
for(i in 1: length(data)){data[,i]<-gsub("£","",data[,i]) }
```

But why doesn't the apply call work?

Comment: `1` in `apply` is for row operations... for columns you should use `2`. Either way, for column operations `lapply` or `sapply` are preferable.

Comment: Try `data[] <- lapply(data, function(x) gsub("£", "", x))`.

Comment: @Roland good idea, bad naming. data is a function thus you'll get a `closure is not subsettable` kind of error.

Comment: @MattBannert From OP's code I've assumed they have a data.frame `data`. Then this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Point taken :) . still though since the example is not reproducible it might be noteworthy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the next best reproducible example. Though there might be a better / faster (vectorized) way if I thought a little harder. But since you asked for apply:

```
# just turn it to characters in order to 
# turn . to , ... was just the first dataset that came to
# but as character should not be necessary for your data
ds[] <- sapply(mtcars,function(x) gsub("\\.",",",as.character(x)))
```